# Elegant approach to finding largest $n$ such that $n\lg(n) \leq 10^6$

Tags: algorithms

I'm studying [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), and solving problems listed after each chapter. I'm curious about problem 1-1. That is right after Chapter 1.

The question is, what is the best way to find the largest integer $n$ such that $n \lg(n) \leq 10^6$.

The simplest but the longest one is substitution. Are there some elegant ways to solve this?

Some explanations: $n$ is what I should calculate - total quantity of input elements, $10^6$ - time in microseconds - total algorithm running time. I should figure out $n_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: Crossposted on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406707/elegant-way-to-solve-n-lgn-le-106).

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073). If you really want the [math perspective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406707/elegant-way-to-solve-n-log-2n-le-106) and the CS perspective, tailor the question to each site, and at least have the decency to link the questions to each other.

Comment: @Gilles wow! So many good explanations! Tank you very much. Yesterday I posted my question here but it was downvoted without providing me with any answers or explanations. There was only one comment telling me that My question is unrelated to this website. So I asked whether I should delete my question and reposted it on math.se. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @DaddyM Oh, you'd [posted it first on Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/elegant-approach-to-solve-nlgn-106?noredirect=1), which is a site for [research-level TCS only](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq). It was then migrated here, to the all-levels CS site. I hadn't realized you'd posted on Math on the advice of comments, and then the question was migrated from CSTheory.SE to CS.SE. I apologize for my harsh comment.

Answer (score 7):

We just solve $x \log x = 10^6$ and round down. This sort of equation typically does not have a closed form solution (so what, closed form solutions are so 18th century, we've got computers now), so we just [feed this into a computer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%20%2a%20Log%5Bn%5D%20==%2010%5E6) and we get $n \approx 87847.5$, so the answer is 87847.

You did ask for the most elegant approach, you know, and that would be to use the right tool.

Now, you could also wonder how you would compute this by hand if you found yourself in the middle of a jungle. You could use the [iteration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) (is this what you called substitution?). Write the equation in the form of a fixed point:
$$x = \frac{10^6}{\log x}$$
Start with any initial guess for $x$ and keep applying the right-hand side. With some luck, you converge. You find a python in the jungle and make it compute:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = 42
>>> for i in range(20):
...    print x
...    x = 1000000.0/math.log(x)
... 
42
267546.386419
80018.8957423
88573.8173924
87784.0460781
87853.1196966
87847.0493964
87847.5826391
87847.5357949
87847.5399101
87847.5395486
87847.5395803
87847.5395775
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
```

That was kind of slow. A better method would be [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). We are looking for the root of $f(x) = x \log x - 10^6$. The derivative is $f'(x) = 1 + \log x$ so the Newton's method step is
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{x_n \log x_n - 10^6}{1 + \log x_n}.$$ 
So now we get:

```
>>> x = 42
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print (x)
...     x = x - (x * math.log(x) - 1000000.0)/(1 + math.log(x))
... 
42
211083.102152
91333.5177989
87852.9643949
87847.5395913
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
87847.5395778
```

Much better.

Answer (score 3):

This to me looks like a case for good old-fashined binary search.

Notice that $n\log n$ is strictly increasing as $n$ increases. So if you try an $m$ and find that $m\log m \leq 10^6$, then you know $n \geq m$. Likewise, if
$m \log m > 10^6$, then $n < m$.

You can do this to keep cutting your search space in half. Your starting lower bound is $0$, and your starting upper bound is $10^6$, since $10^6 \cdot \log (10^6) > 10^6$.

You try $m$ as $start +\frac{start-end}{2}$ each time. If $m\log m \leq 10^6$, then your lower bound is $m$, and if it is greater, your upper bound changes to $m$. You repeat until you have narrowed it down to a single solution, remembering that your lower bound is an inclusive lower bound.

This runs in $O(\log k)$ time for an interval of width $k$, so for $k = 10^6$, it should run decently fast.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, if $n\log n = x$, then $n \approx x/\log x$. This won't give you the optimal $n$, but for large $x$ it's a pretty good approximation since
$$ \frac{x}{\log x} \log \frac{x}{\log x} = \frac{x}{\log x} (\log x - \log\log x) = x \left(1 - \frac{\log\log x}{\log x}\right).$$

Comment: However, for $x \approx 2^{20}$, $\lg x = 20$ is not very large, so this gives an error of about $21.6\%$.

Answer (score 2):

In the edition I have, $\lg n$ means $\log_2 n$, so I suspect the authors had in mind something like the following:

Since $10^6 \lesssim 2^{20} = 16.2^{16}$, one needs $n$ to be a little bit less than $65536$, and is somewhat larger than $32768$.  A quick binary search then yields $n_\text{max} = 62746$.  This can be calculated quickly even with just the simple calculator app that comes with most operating systems, by computing $n \log n/\log 2$ for a few values of $n$.

(This is essentially the same [answer given by Michael C. Grant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406733/3362) at [math.se], where the version of the question also confirms that $\lg n = \log_2 n$ is intended.)